# Understanding of Fourier transform of the convolution of two distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

In Yosida's *Functional Analysis*, he covers a topic on the Fourier transform of the convolution given by distributions (at the end of Section 3, Chapter 6). He begins by pointing out the Fourier transform of a distribution $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n} $with compact support ($T\in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$) is given by a function
$$
\hat{T} (\xi) =(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}T_{[x]}(e^{-i\langle x,\xi \rangle}),
$$
where the subscript $[x]$ is marked to indicate $T$ acts on functions of the variable $x$. My interpretation for this result is that $\hat{T}$, as a tempered distribution, can be written in terms of integration:
$$
\hat{T}(\varphi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \hat{T}(\xi) \varphi(\xi) \ d\xi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}T_{[x]}(e^{-i\langle x,\xi \rangle}) \varphi(\xi) \ d\xi
$$
for each Schwartz function $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

**Question 1.** Is my interpretation correct? I can't see it clearly when I read the proof, so I would like to ask for clarification.

I' m confused when he gives the Fourier transform of the convolution quoted as follows:

> **Theorem.** If $T\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then
> $$
> \widehat{T\ast \varphi} = (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\hat{\varphi}\hat{T} \tag{1}
> $$
> If $T_{1}\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $T_{2}\in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then
> $$
> \widehat{T_{1}\ast T_{2}} = (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\hat{T_{2}}\cdot \hat{T_{1}} \tag{2},
> $$
> which has a sense sense $\hat{T_{2}}$ is given by a function.

My interpretation for Equation (1) is that this equation holds as both sides of the objects are seen as tempered distributions since $\hat{T}$ is nothing but a tempered distribution. However, I am confused by his explanation on $\hat{T_{2}}$ in this Theorem and that in the proof of Equation (2). Truly, $\hat{T_{2}}$ should be viewed as a function since it makes no sense to speak of multiplication of two distributions (at least at this point), but his proof of Equation (2) seems to indicate $\hat{T_{2}}$ should be a tempered distribution. Let me quote the proof as follows:

> **Proof of Equation (2).** Let $\psi_{\varepsilon}$ be the regularization $T_{2}\ast \psi_{\varepsilon}$. Then the Fourier transform of
> $$
> T_{1}\ast \psi_{\varepsilon} = T_{1}\ast (T_{2}\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}) = (T_{1}\ast T_{2})\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}
> $$
> is by Equation (1), equal to
> $$
> (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}} \hat{T_{1}} \cdot \hat{\psi_{\varepsilon}} 
> = (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}} \hat{T_{1}} \cdot (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\hat{T_{2}}\cdot \hat{\varphi_{\varepsilon}} 
> = (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}} \widehat{T_{1}\ast T_{2}} \cdot \hat{\varphi_{\varepsilon}}. \tag{3}
> $$
> Hence we obtain Equation (2) by letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ and using $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \hat{\varphi_{\varepsilon}}(x)=1$.

You can see in Equation (3), the middle term is given by Equation (1) and because of that, $\hat{T_{2}}$ should be viewed as a tempered distribution.

**Question 2.** What does Equation (2) truly mean? Do I misunderstand the whole thing?

Thank you first for kindly reading this long post, and I will appreciate any comment and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To question 1:

Yes it means that there is a function (the one given) so that $\hat{T}$ is given by integration against that function.

### To question 2:

Equation 1 also holds in the sense of functions if $T \in \mathcal{E}^\prime$ and we identify $\hat T$ with the $C^\infty$ function corresponding to it. It even follows that $T * \varphi \in \mathcal{S}$ and so the whole equation can be interpreted in the sense of functions. It is also important to keep the compatibility of the Fourier transform and the convolution in mind.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and this clears up my confusion, but would you mind explaining what you mean by the compatibility of the Fourier transform and the convolution? Thanks!

Comment: @Eric i mean that the (functional) Fourier transform of a function and the distributional Fourier transform of the distribution associated to that function can be identified with each other in natural way under certain conditions. Similarly the convolution of a distribution/function with a function (seen as a function) and the distributional convolution of a distribution with the distribution associated to a function can be identified under certain circumstances.